# How to avoid glitching in collection view cells while dragging the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view that can be scrolled both horizontally and vertically. I've implemented it using compositional layout. When I make fast dragging actions across the screen vertically / horizontally I can see the cells appearing to be gltiched or overlaid.
How to avoid this?

I've attached a gif to show the behaviour.

[image: glitch]

Comment: Please share the code in the form of the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Not to mention, I cannot see even the GIF you mentioned.

Comment: I've edited the question now. Is the gif visible?

Comment: @Dracarys - you have essentially said: *"I wrote some code and it causes 'glitches' ... How can I fix it?"* -- Without showing us the code you've written, there is no way anybody can offer suggestions to fix it. Please review [ask].